# Image dragging is slow in ios 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an ipad app with video recording and image dragging functionalities both for ios 5 and ios 6.

I have used 'ScreenCapture' class files for video recording and 'Draggable' class files for image dragging.

Now the problem is that when i use 'ScreenCapture' class , the image dragging functionality becomes slow and little jerky. And when i remove that 'ScreenCapture' class, the dragging works fine(without video recording).

This both functionalities woke fine for ios 5. But when try to run in ios 6, image dragging becomes slow due to 'ScreenCapture'.

How can i do this?

**CODE USED :-

```
  //  For image dragging.......


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if (isImageRemove)
    {
        imgcharacter = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
        imgobject = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

    }

    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:imgcharacter];
    startlocation =pt;

    imgcharacter.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    imgobject.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    int count;

    if (isImageRemove)
   {
        Images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        int value = [touch view].tag;

       int inx=0;
        for (int i1=0; i1<[[self.view subviews] count]; i1++) {
            if ([[[[self.view subviews]objectAtIndex:i1]valueForKey:@"tag"]intValue]==value) {
                inx=i1;
                break; 
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"index = %d",inx);

        count =   [self.view.subviews count];
        NSLog(@"count = %d",count);

        UIView* subview;


        if ((subview = [[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:inx]))
        {
            if ([touch view].tag >0)
            {
                NSLog(@"subview = %@",subview);
                [subview removeFromSuperview];
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"subview = %@",[self.view subviews]);
            }
        }

    }
    else 
    {

        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    }

}


   // For Video recording.......

- (IBAction)btnRecording_Pressed:(id)sender {
    if (Isrecording ==YES)
    {
        [voiceRecorder stop];
        [captureview stopRecording];

        AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        NSError *err = nil;
        [audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
        if(err)
        {
            NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
            return;
        }
        [audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];

        err = nil;
        if(err){
            NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
            return;
        }

        recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

        [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
        [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
        [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];

        NSString *recorderFilePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

        recorderFilePath = [recorderFilePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tempRecording.caf"];
        NSURL *urls = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath];
        err = nil;
        voiceRecorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:urls settings:recordSetting error:&err];

        if(!voiceRecorder){
            NSLog(@"recorder: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
            UIAlertView *alert =
            [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                                       message: [err localizedDescription]
                                      delegate: nil
                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            return;
        }

        //prepare to record
        [voiceRecorder setDelegate:self];
        [voiceRecorder prepareToRecord];

        //scrren short of screen

        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
        else
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);


        [captureview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

        UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewImage, 1.0);

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);      

        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"VideoScreen.jpg"];

        [imageData writeToFile:documentsDirectory atomically:YES];

        [voiceRecorder record];

        [captureview performSelector:@selector(startRecording) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

        Isrecording =NO;
        [btnRecord setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else if (!Isrecording)
    {
        imgDustbin.hidden =NO;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] setValue:@"YES" forKey:@"DUSTBIN"];

        [voiceRecorder stop];
        [captureview stopRecording];
        [self createVideo];
        Isrecording=YES;
        [btnRecord setTitle:@"Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: @RohanKapur - i have added my code.

Comment: You should use gesture recognizers, touchesMoved: is **so** old school!

Comment: I think that's not your fault at all as ios 6 doesn't provide the functionality of Screen Gesture and that's why it causes that jerky effect, I Guess. Just See this : http://www.macworld.com.au/blogs/8-things-that-still-bug-us-in-ios-6-73891/

Comment: @RohanKapur - thanks for reply. I have already tried touchesMoved, but it does not effect anything and the problem is same. I noticed that this problem is due to 'ScreenCapture' functionality(i.e video recording) , is is so ?

Comment: Try building the app for analyzing, then running the time profiler and seeing what code is sucking up the most CPU. That's what I would do...